# How do I load data from files stored on multiple folders into the database using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have lot of files stored in separate folders that I would like to extract and insert into a single table in SQL Server database. The folders setup is something like shown below:

```
Folder 1  
 |--> SubFolder 1.1  
 |     |--> File 1  
 |     |--> File 2  
 |--> SubFolder 1.2  
 |     |--> File 1  
 |     |--> File 2
 |--> SubFolder 1.3  
       |--> File 1  
       |--> File 2
```

There are around 100 sub folders and all of them have two **.txt** files in them that I need to extract.

I need to load the data into a table structured as shown below

```
Column1         Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5     Column6  
-------------   ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------
SubFolderName   File1Col1   File1Col2   File1Col3   File1Col4   File2Col1
```

Does anybody know how I can do this using SSIS?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `Traverse subfolders` option under the `Foreach File Enumerator` option available in `Foreach Loop container`. *Foreach Loop container* is available on the *Control Flow* task.

Here are few examples the illustrate the Foreach File Loop enumeration:

[**How To – Tasks and Transformations: Foreach File Loop**](http://www.varigence.com/blog/how-to-tasks-and-transformations-foreach-file-loop.html)

[**SSIS Package Containers- Part 5: Foreach Loop Containers**](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DonnyJohns/ssas/1692/ssis-package-containers-part-5-foreach-loop-containers)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following steps:

1. You can use the `Foreach File Enumerator` and `Traverse subfolders`
   options to iterate through the files, Keep in mind that you should
   use the `Fully qualified` and save the filepath into the user
   variable called `IncomingFile`.
2. You can create variables called `SubFolderName` and `FileName`.
3. Pass the IncomingFile variable as readonly variable and
   subfolderName and FileName as ReadWriteVariable . You can use the
   script component to fetch the subfoldername.

   ```
   var incomingFile = Dts.Variables["IncomingFile"].Value.ToString();

   FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileFullPath);

   string subFolderPath = fileInfo.Directory.Name;
   string fileName = fileInfo.Name;

   Dts.Variables["SubFolderName"].Value = subFolderPath;
   Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value = fileName;
   ```
4. Drag two dataflow which connects to the ScriptComponet. You should
   write the precedence constraint as follows[for both evaluation
   operation should be "Expression"].

   ```
       For DataFlow 1 -> `@FileName=="Text 1"`
       For DataFlow 2 -> `@FileName=="Text 2"`
   ```
5. In your dataflow 1 use the derived column and use the SubFolderName
   variable to map to "Column1" in your example. Other columns will be
   mapped from your txt file, other than "Column6".
6. In your dataflow 2, Stage the data into SQL server with the
   subfoldername.
7. Write the stored procedure which updates your Coloumn 6 table by
   comparing the subfolder name.
8. Use `SQL Execute task` to run the stored procedure.

Your package will be looks something as follows.

[image]

Hope this helps!